# Can I replace two switches with a single dimmer?

Tags: dimmer-switch

In my flat I have two switches on the same wall socket that turn on two different lights.
I would like to replace the two small switches with dimmers but given that I'm planning to use them together, I would like to install a single dimmer that works on both lights.
Is it possible to do so? What should I consider to avoid mistakes/issues?
Thank you

EDIT: This is a photo of the current wiring for the two switches:
[image: wiring for the socket]

Comment: Based on terminology, it sounds like you are not in the US/Canada - so just comment instead of an answer. Generally, the key issue is whether the existing switches/lights are on the same circuit breaker. If they are, this is fine and really simple. If they are on separate circuit breakers then it could be a little more complicated or a lot more complicated, depending on how the existing switches & lights are wired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. Yep I'm in EU. Sorry about my terminology. I assume the switches are on the same circuit breaker as on the breaker boxes there's one that turn off most of the room's electricity (the two lights included).

Comment: The terminology is actually a *good* thing, because it right away told me "probably Europe". Next step is to: turn off the breaker, pull out the switches (**without disconnecting any wires**) and take/upload pictures showing how all the wires connect to the switches.

Comment: FYI, in the US (and likely many other places too) you are not supposed to do your own electrical work in a rented home. "flat", to me, implies "rented apartment" in the US context. There are exceptions - an apartment can be owned, typically as a "condominium" and then it is the same (as far as electrical work, etc.) generally as a single-family home. So please clarify if this is a rental or not, and if it is a rental then (possibly country dependent) it may be that you should not be doing this work yourself.

Comment: In the U.S. wall sockets can not be on a dimmer,  we may have a terminology difference but a receptacle(s)  controlled by a switch can not be a dimmer by code. If your lights (sockets) are in the ceiling it may be possible if on the same circuit.

Comment: I take it both lights are turned off by the same breaker in your consumer unit (breaker box)?

Comment: Thank you @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact and the others for your help, I edited the post uploading a photo of the current wiring, and I'm planning to replace the switches with this kind of dimmer: https://www.amazon.de/LED-Dimmer-MK-II-Industries-Dimmschalter-Dimmbare/dp/B08J4J3LFP/